# How to install Ethereum?

Tags: 12.04

Using Ubuntu 12.04, How do I install this correctly?

> [Ethereum](http://www.ethereum.org/) is a next-generation distributed cryptographic ledger that is
>   designed to allow users to encode advanced transaction types, smart
>   contracts and decentralized applications into the blockchain. Ethereum
>   will support custom currencies or "colored coins", financial
>   derivatives, and much more, but unlike many previous networks that
>   attempted to accomplish the same thing Ethereum does not attempt to
>   constrain users into using specific "features"; instead, the ledger
>   includes a built-in Turing-complete programming language that can be
>   used to construct any kind of contract that can be mathematically
>   defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are packages you need to build Ethereum:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev libcrypto++-dev 
git cmake libboost-all-dev automake libtool libleveldb-dev 
yasm unzip libminiupnpc-dev
```

Then grab and build the latest cryptopp:

```
mkdir cryptopp562
cd cryptopp562
wget http://www.cryptopp.com/cryptopp562.zip
unzip cryptopp562.zip
make
cd ..
```

Then grab and build the SECP256k1 crypto lib:

```
wget http://gavwood.com/secp256k1.tar.bz2
tar xjf secp256k1.tar.bz2
cd secp256k1
./configure && make
cd ..
```

Then build the client; for this you can either get the latest sources from the Git repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum
mkdir cpp-ethereum-build
cd cpp-ethereum-build
cmake ../cpp-ethereum -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
cd ..
```

Or, if you’re building from the released tarball:

```
tar xzf cpp-ethereum-poc-1.tar.gz
mkdir cpp-ethereum-build
cd cpp-ethereum-build
cmake ../cpp-ethereum-poc-1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
cd ..
```

You might then Configure a Server. If you want to build the GUI client, AlephZero, you’ll need to make sure you have Qt installed:

```
 sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

And then just build it:

```
cd cpp-ethereum-build
mkdir alephzero
cd alephzero
qmake ../../cpp-ethereum-poc-1/alephzero
make
```

Note: if you’re building from the GitHub repo, you’ll want cpp-ethereum instead of cpp-ethereum-poc-1!

Once done, you can run your experimental Ethereum client with `./alephzero`.

[SOURCE](http://ethereum-miner.tumblr.com/post/75205573886/linux-ubuntu-install-guide)

- installation is based on 13.04 but other Ubuntu releases should be fine with the same installation.

Comment: "git: 'cmake' is not a git command." Typo or difference in o/s vers?

Comment: no see the 1st command ;) it is in the repos: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmake

Comment: sigh to myself. thx!

Comment: that's ok :D happens ;)

Comment: It worked using a couple of modifications shown [here](http://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/203/how-to-install-ethereum-on-ubuntu-12-04#latest)